# How to send/receive data file over socket?

Tags: python, file, sockets, data-transfer

I am writing a socket programming with Python in order to send/receive a file over TCP.

While I am sending/receiving data, I figured out it neither sent nor received the part of files.

Here is a part to send a part of data based on the size of the buffer.

```
  msg[i] = file[i].read()
  file[i].close()
  while 1:
     tdata[i], msg[i] = msg[i][:buf], msg[i][buf:]
     c.send(tdata[i])

     if len(msg[i]) < buf:
        break
```

Please help me out how to send/receive the whole data completely.

Comment: Which part of the file is missing? Do you get any errors at the sender or receiver?

Answer (score 3):

It will stop sending when `len(msg[i]) < buf`, so the end of data may be missing.

If you want to send all of msg[i], it's better to do:

```
while msg[i]:
    tdata[i], msg[i] = msg[i][:buf], msg[i][buf:]
    c.sendall(tdata[i])
```

or just send it in one go:

```
c.sendall(msg[i])
```

Note that `send()` will return how many bytes were actually sent (because it won't necessarily send all of them), so if you want to send all (which is usually the case) use `sendall()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfileobj(open('data'), c.makefile('wb'))
```

This is how the SimpleHTTPServer module does it.